# What is the time complexity of Arrays,sort(String [])

Tags: java, arrays, string, time, time-complexity

```
String str[] = {"Hello", "World", "John", "Doe"};
Arrays.sort(str);
System.out.prinltn(Arrays.toString(str));
```

I know Arrays.sort(int[]) will have time complexity of O(nlgn). But what about string array. Since sorting string array uses compareTo function internally to compare two string. Will it change the equation ?

Comment: Will this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571586/will-arrays-sort-increase-time-complexity-and-space-time-complexity

Comment: @asn21 - no that is not a relevant answer; the problem in this question is about how to 'mix' the concept that comparing two strings is itself an operation whose time complexity isn't easily disregarded as `O(1)`.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with saying: **Sorting is O(n logn)** is that this is an incomplete and therefore nebulous, undefined statement. It is unclear what it means. The problem is: You have failed to define what `n` is.

Now, in practice, `n` is usually obvious from context. For example, If I say: "Sorting an array of integers is O(n logn) assuming an optimal sorting algorithm", just about everybody who hears this will immediately realize that, whilst I didn't explicitly say what `n` is, clearly I mean: *n = the number of ints in that array*.

So let's go back to your problem: Now n is no longer clear.

Is n the # of strings in the array? Is n the average # of characters for all strings in that array?

We're really talking about 2 separate variables here. So, to properly describe the performance characteristics in terms of big-O notation for this problem, you'd say something like:

- Given: `String[] str`, for example: `str  = {"Hello", "World", "John", "Doe"}`
- Let `n` be the number of elements in the `str` array.
- Let `m` be the average # of characters for the strings in the `str` array
- Then, calling `Arrays.sort(str)` on this array would have the performance characteristic of `O(m * n log n)`.

The reason it's O(m*n logn) is because the sorting algorithm itself will run `O(n logn)` comparison operations in order to perform the sort. And each comparison operation takes `O(m)` time to finish, though that is very much the worst case scenario: Given, say, `Hello` and `World`, even though `m = 5` for those two, the comparison completes after only 1 step; the algorithm compares `H` and `W` and answers immediately, never even looking at `ello` or `orld`. But if the strings are `Hello1`, `Hello2`, `Hello3` and `Hello4`, then that's a guaranteed 5 'steps' for every time 2 strings are compared, and there will be `O(n logn)` comparisons.